# The best way to show error/warning is make it in view or pass with custom attribute in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, error-handling

I have some hesistation about to show my custom errors/warnings which are not gotten from controller.

I use two different ways to do it. First one is:

```
[MyHandlingAttribute("MyPage_FirstName_Required_Error")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

And the second way is on js:

```
if($('#FirstName').val() == "")
    showMyCustomAlertOrHint();
```

First one is looking better but it seems like you should go to the controller to handle it. So it's a cost. The second one seems more effective and fast depends on being in client side.

If I am wrong please set me straight.

Comment: The first one will validate on both the client and the server is your attribute implements `IClientValidatable`. Refer [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1) for examples of how to implement validation. Do not use the second way - anyone can by-pass it, so you then need to manually repeat that validation again on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first approach - annotate your view model with validation attributes and still enable client side validations in config file. See this **[nice tutorial](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/enable-client-side-valiation-in-mvc)**. Then you have a clean nice code without any unnecessary round trips to the controller and back.

Enable client side validation:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Include the crucial JS files:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
```

Render the desired input field and corresponding validation message:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` like 
on this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model)

```
[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

And as I know this approach provides both side validation, just use next helpers with js scripts like on the article.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
```